# Django How to send signals for add or remove user from group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to use signals for add and remove user from groups but I am not understanding where I am doing wrong. here is my code:

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def group(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        group = Group.objects.get(name='myauthors')
        if instance.is_blog_author == True:
           instance.groups.add(group)
        elif instance.is_blog_author == False:
             instance.groups.remove(group)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @BrianD no. I am not getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

create a `signals.py` file in your app

in your `apps.py` file,
overide the `ready` method of your `appConfig` class Like so

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class MyAppClassConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = '<app_name>'



  def ready(self):
        from . import signals # import your signals here
```

`init.py` file of the app do this

```
default_app_config = '<app_name>.apps.MyAppClassConfig'
```

Then add your code to `signals.py`

Also show your model class and the error you are getting, i'm posting this answer based on assumptions.

#PS, I don't have enough reputation to post a comment hence using the answer box. such a shame.